# Transform an array to a different shape using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to change the following:

```
export const data = [
  {
    beneficiary_name: "angloss american capital",
    period: "current_6_month",
    payment_amount: 684130564
  },
  {
    beneficiary_name: "angloss american capital",
    period: "previous_6_month",
    payment_amount: 273000000
  }
];
```

to

```
[
    {
        beneficiary_name: 'angloss american capital',
        current_6_month: 684130564,
        previous_6_month: 273000000
    }
]
```

How can I do this by using map(), reduce() or filter(). Or by using a library like lodash?

Comment: It can be done with `reduce()`, but I think an ordinary `forEach()` loop will probably be easier. Create a temporary object that uses the beneficiary name as the keys, so you can merge all the related objects. Then use `Object.values()` at the end to get the values as an array.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The result is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-ritchie-jddbm. The aim was to get pointed to the right direction by being succinct and straight to the point. Not get free coding service.